# Getting Null from JSON Data encoded in PHP, outputting to Java

Tags: java, php, android, json

My JSON output in PHP is done this way:

```
 print json_encode(array('rate' => $topcat, 'hometown' => $hometown, 'talk' => $talk));
```

My JSON output looks like this in my browser:

{"rate":"Movies","hometown":"Seattle, WA","talk":"Movies"}

in Java/Android I do this:

protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

```
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


            Hometown = json_data.getString("hometown");
            FavCategory = json_data.getString("rate");              
            Talk = json_data.getString("talk");



        }
    } catch (JSONException e1) {

    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (Hometown.equals("")) {
        Hometown = "Not Specified";
    }

    tvHometown.setText(Hometown);
    tvRate.setText(FavCategory);
    tvTalk.setText(Talk);

    Log.d("Log: ", Hometown + " " + FavCategory + " " + Talk);

}
```

}

On that Log, I get this:  `Seattle, WA, null, null`

Can anyone see why?

**EDIT:  New Java Code, still getting error:**

```
String homeTown = "", favCategory = "", favTalk = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(result);

            homeTown = jsonData.getString("hometown");
            favCategory = jsonData.getString("rate");
            favTalk = jsonData.getString("talk");


            tvHometown.setText(homeTown);
            tvRate.setText(favCategory);
            tvTalk.setText(favTalk);




} catch (JSONException e1) {

    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting an exception:

```
02-05 08:51:48.078: E/log_tag(22958): Error in http connection org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: With the new code, are you getting a `null`, or is the code throwing an exception? Which line, specifically?

Comment: @MattBall Ok, maybe null was wrong. I am getting a JSONException as seen above (just added).

Comment: I don't see anything in your code about a `JSONArray`. Are you sure the code your app is running is actually what's in the question?

Comment: I think I just caught something on PHP side... will let you know in a couple minutes...

Comment: @MattBall Got it!  Somehow it got changed to `echo` from `print` on the PHP side when I was encoding... marking you correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite [the PHP vocabulary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), the top-level element of this JSON:

```
{"rate":"Movies","hometown":"Seattle, WA","talk":"Movies"}
```

is [an **object** (a key-value mapping), *not* an **array**](http://json.org/). The `{}`s are a dead giveaway.

Change this

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

to this:

```
JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(result);
```

and go from there:

```
String hometown = jsonData.getString("hometown");
String favCategory = jsonData.getString("rate");              
String talk = jsonData.getString("talk");
```

Note how, [as a matter of good Java style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java), I use `lowerCamelCased` variable names.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a square bracket to indicate that it is a JSONArray your result is in JSONObject if you want to get the data of each JSONArray your result should be more like this

```
{"rate": ["samplevalue","samplevalue"],"Movies" : ["samplevalue","samplevalue"],"hometown":["Seattle, WA"],"talk":["Movies"]}
```